# Centering ListView in Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to make a login / registration screens with a logo. I need them responsive, so the can fit most of mobile screens. For achieving that, I've used ListView. However, I just need to center the ListView inside my layout. Any suggestions?

Here is my attempt:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', scale: 3.0,),
            InputField('enter email address', Icons.email, TextInputType.emailAddress),
            PasswordInputField('enter password', Icons.lock, TextInputType.text),
            RoundBtn('SIGN IN', signIn),
            RoundBtn('SIGN UP', () => {}),
            OutlineBtn('FORGOT PASSWORD?', () => {})
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

[Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfer4.png)
[Registration Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSXac.png)

Comment: maybe shrinkWrap: true, can help

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use SingleChildScrollView instead of ListView.
Try this...

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png', scale: 3.0,),
              InputField('enter email address', Icons.email, TextInputType.emailAddress),
              PasswordInputField('enter password', Icons.lock, TextInputType.text),
              RoundBtn('SIGN IN', signIn),
              RoundBtn('SIGN UP', () => {}),
              OutlineBtn('FORGOT PASSWORD?', () => {})
            ],
          ),
        ),)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

ListView cannot be added to the center of the screen. Still, no official documentation is there. But still, if you want to do

**Example:**

```
Center(
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(child: Text('Text1')),
        Center(child: Text('Text2')),
        Center(child: Text('Text3')),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- Use `shrinkWrap: true` in ListView.

```
 child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      ......
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CustomScrollView` and `SliverFillRemaining`  instead of using `ListView`.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverFillRemaining(
        hasScrollBody: false,
        child: Center(
          child: new Text('ABC')
        ),
      ),
    ]
  )
);
```